# HandleErrorAttribute working example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When you create a new VS project web application you get an Error.cshtml and I can not get why?

I searched the internet and could not find a working example on how to display the Error.cshtml. I did found written example of what to do but they do not work for me.

The changes that I did are: change the web.config to have  and on About method I throw an exception. But I still get YSOD instead of the Error.cshtml.

So what is the point of creating the Error.cshtml if the MVC application will not use it? Am I still missing something?

Is the creation of an ErrorController necessary?

Comment: Error controller is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify *customErrors* property in web config to mode *on*:

```
 <system.web>
   <customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
 </system.web>
```

or :

```
  <system.web>
   <customErrors mode="On" 
    defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml">
   </customErrors>
 </system.web>
```

Comment: Already done this and it does not work. Can you provide a VS project where this works?

Comment: It works but you have to write this in the Web.config and not uncomment the customerrors from Web.Debug.config. I do not know why the example is placed there.

Answer (score 0):

When you catch an exception you get enough information from the that, so you can also pass that information via model to the Error.cshtml page

You may try IExceptionFilter filter handling in your project.